# Filter records in database according to the selected checkboxes using MVC

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Ajax.BeginForm in my razor view. I want to have 3 check boxes.

1. Begineer
2. Intemidiate
3. advance

checkoxes can select for any combination. When I clicked submit button bellow method in my controller will triggered.

```
public PartialViewResult SearchCourseCriteria(){

        var courses = from s in db.CourseCategories
                      select s;
        return PartialView("_Courses", courses);

}
```

This is my view

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchCourseCriteria", new AjaxOptions
    {
       UpdateTargetId = "CourseList",    
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,  
       HttpMethod = "GET"
    }))
    {
        td>
           @Html.CheckBoxFor()                                        
        </td>

        <td>
           <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn " />
        </td>

   }
```

In my model there is field called CourseLevel. I want to know How to filter courses according to the selected checkboxes. 
EX : If I select begineer and Intermidiate checkboex. I want to get all courseCategories from that levels. I dont know how to get that result. Help please.

Comment: Use a `where CourseLevel.Contains(??)` clause based on the values of your checkboxes.

Comment: I know that thing, i don't  know how to use checkboxex in my view and parse it to method. :(

Comment: Edit you question to show how how you generate the checkboxes in the view

Comment: I edited question and inserted how is my view looks like. There is no checkboxes there. I don't know actually how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you view, generate 3 checkboxes for each value

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="courselevel" value="Begineer" /> // Beginner?
  <span>Begineer</span>
<label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="courselevel" value="Intemidiate" /> // Intermediate?
  <span>Intemidiate</span>
<label>
... // ditto for advance
```

Then add a parameter to the method

```
public PartialViewResult SearchCourseCriteria(string[] CourseLevel)
```

The value of CourseLevel will be an array of the selected checkboxes, for example `[ "Begineer", "advance" ]` if you checked the first and third checkboxes

You can then modify you query to

```
var courses  = from s in db.CourseCategories
               where CourseLevel.Contains(s.CourseLevel)
               select s;
```

or

```
var courses= db.CourseCategories.Where(c => CourseLevel.Contains(c.CourseLevel));
```

Side note: I would recommend you use an `enum` to define the values for `CourseLevel`

Comment: Thank you very much @stephen Its is really helpful and working perfectly. Thank you so much again.